# Use of comma following prepositional phrase

Tags: punctuation, commas

Is a comma required after the date (year only or day of week only) that is in a prepositional phrase before the subject of the sentence?  For example:

> In 1966 I began college.

Comment: It's just an inversion of the "default" sequence for such clauses in English - *"I began college in 1966"*. If the relocated [Modifying Phrase](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/as-like-at-beginning.aspx) is really short, you certainly don't *need* the comma to maintain legibility.

Answer (score 4):

You have to ask how strong an interruption to the sentence the prepositional phrase makes. I would say that in that case the answer was *not very*, and that consequently no comma was needed.

Comment: I think it just changes the emphasis a bit. With the comma, there's a stronger emphasis on the year because of the pause.