# In Figure X, ... - with Comma?

Tags: commas

What of the following examples is better:

> In Figure 1, we show that A performs better than B.

or

> In Figure 1 we show that A performs better than B.

When looking through a few journals I found that both versions are used. I usually used it with a comma because when I did not use a comma, I would need to skip the comma also for

> In this case we maximize X.

and

> In this section we show that

to assure consistency.

Comment: Related question, [Comma after “In Section 2”, “In what follows”, or “In 1999”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294864/comma-after-in-section-2-in-what-follows-or-in-1999) and [Comma after introductory phrases](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52091/comma-after-introductory-phrases) and [Use of comma following prepositional phrase](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83208/use-of-comma-following-prepositional-phrase). There are more if you use the [search box](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=comma+after+prepositional+phrase).

Comment: I could probably dredge up a style guide advocating inconsistency here: 'If the quasi-locative contains over 5 words, include a comma'. If you have a stickler for a boss, ask what they want. Otherwise, trust that the journals are all reasonably edited (though I'd omit the commas in all your examples; I like the modern trend towards light punctuation. Whilst reserving the right to add commas to signal pauses as well as to clarify.)